# Detect When Specific "Legend" element is visible on the web page using JavaScript Only (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to detect, with JavaScript, when this particular element appears on the page? There re multiple legend elements that are hidden and displayed based on user selections. I cannot touch/change the mark-up of the web app, I have to work with what is currently there.

```
        <legend>Success! We've connected to your bank. Choose an account to fund your new Bank of the West account.</legend>
```

I was playing around/testing with the below code I got from another website but it doesn't work (I tried both display/none and visibility/hidden). I don't understand how the legend variable in the function returns the actual text in the legend element but is some how supposed to generate a boolean value because of this line:

```
var foundAndVisible = legend && (window.getComputedStyle(legend).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "hidden");
```

```
function _dtmCheckFundingPage() {
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        var legend = document.evaluate("//legend[contains(., 'Choose an account to fund your new Bank of the West account.')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
        console.log(" LEGEND HOLDS: ", legend);
        //var foundAndVisible = legend && (window.getComputedStyle(legend).getPropertyValue("display") == "none"); // of course, replace display/none by visibility/hidden 
        var foundAndVisible = legend && (window.getComputedStyle(legend).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "hidden"); // of course, replace display/none by visibility/hidden 
        console.log(" B =============== IN FUNDING PAGE CHECK - foundAndVisible holds: " + foundAndVisible);
        if (foundAndVisible) {
            clearInterval(t);
            console.log("==========found!");
        }
    }, 1000); // check every second
};
```

Comment: do you know how the hidden <legend>s are hidden when they are ? via dispaly:none for example, or visibility:hidden ?

Comment: maybe this https://gist.github.com/davidtheclark/5515733#file-iselementinviewport-js

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked upwards the parent hierarchy? Watching the elements status update in console. 
It is possible that the visibility of a parent is being changed.
In that case, you can still use your code, add references to the parents and children in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had to change the "foundAndVisible" logic:

```
  var foundAndVisible = legend && (window.getComputedStyle(legend).getPropertyValue("display") == "block") && (window.getComputedStyle(legend).getPropertyValue("visibility") == "visible");
```